# Custom environment variable name completion in zsh

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh, zsh-completion, dollar-sign

I am trying to customize how zsh completes environment variable names for my custom command `ee`. Here is the problem: I've defined a custom completion function using `compdef`, and it works perfectly if I type `ee` and hit tab:

```bash
ee <Tab>
```

Here is the output of `^Xh`, which is clear:

```bash
tags in context :completion::complete:ee::
    values  (_spec _echo)
tags in context :completion::complete-fuzzy:ee::
    values  (_spec _echo)
```

The same output `^Xh` produces when I type any text **which doesn't contain the dollar sign**.

However, if I **type the dollar sign**, and then press `Tab`, then the list of completers change radically:

```bash
ee $<Tab>
```

Here what `^Xh` outputs in this case:

```bash
tags in context :completion::complete-fuzzy:-parameter-::
    parameters  (_parameters _parameter autocomplete:_complete:old)
tags in context :completion::complete:-parameter-::
    parameters  (_parameters _parameter autocomplete:_complete:old)
```

Sometimes there are even more elements:

```bash
tags in context :completion::approximate:::
    corrections original  (autocomplete:_approximate:old)
tags in context :completion::approximate-1:-parameter-::
    parameters  (_parameters _parameter autocomplete:_complete:old)
tags in context :completion::complete-fuzzy:-parameter-::
    parameters  (_parameters _parameter autocomplete:_complete:old)
tags in context :completion::complete:-parameter-::
    parameters  (_parameters _parameter autocomplete:_complete:old)
tags in context :completion::correct:::
    corrections original  (autocomplete:_approximate:old)
tags in context :completion::correct-1:-parameter-::
    parameters  (_parameters _parameter autocomplete:_complete:old)
```

As you can see, the list doesn't contain my custom completion function anymore.

The question is: why `$` has such impact on the completion behaviour and how to enable my custom completion even after I type `$`? Didn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came up with after browsing the `zsh` [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html). There is indeed a section dedicated to the question I am interested in (section 20.2.2). I've created separate handlers for usual completion and `parameter` completion like this:

```
_spec () {
  local description="$1"
  shift  # Remove the first argument (description)

  bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line

  _wanted -V values expl "$description" compadd -P '$' "$@"
}

_spec_no_prefix () {
  local description="$1"
  shift  # Remove the first argument (description)

  bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line

  _wanted -V values expl "$description" compadd "$@"
}

_echo () {
  eval "$_setup_ee_completions"
}

_echo_no_prefix () {
  eval "$_setup_ee_completions_no_prefix"
}

compdef _echo_no_prefix ee '-parameter-'
compdef _echo ee
```

Where `_setup_ee_completions` and `_setup_ee_completions_no_prefix` contain the following values respectively:

```
_spec history 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE' 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' 'CHROME_API_VERSION' 'ENV' 'OPENAI_API_KEY' 'PYTHONPATH'
_spec_no_prefix history 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE' 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' 'CHROME_API_VERSION' 'ENV' 'OPENAI_API_KEY' 'PYTHONPATH'
```